# Django superuser not having all permissions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger-ui

While trying to create a Django Rest Framework endpoint for displaying a users permissions, I encountered a problem when it comes to superusers.

I thought superusers had all permissions by default, but when I tried to get all permissions for any user through the Permission-model, I got a length difference between the lists.

```py
# User is a superuser
> len(user.get_all_permissions())
516
> len(Permission.objects.all().distinct())
519
```

Since get_all_permissions() returns a list of strings which are some permutation of data from a permission instead of a QuerySet, I am unable to see exactly which permissions the superuser lacks.

Am I wrong in my impression that a superuser has all permissions? Are there other ways to get all permissions for a user in the form of a Permission QuerySet?
I could always just return the list given by user.get_all_permissions() instead of a QuerySet, but this confuses DRF-Swagger when it comes to the format of possible responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since get_all_permissions() returns a list instead of a QuerySet, I am unable to see exactly which permissions the superuser lacks.

How so? Something like

```
all_permission_ids = {
  f'{app_label}.{codename}'
  for (app_label, codename)
  in Permission.objects.values_list('content_type__app_label', 'codename')
}
missing_permissions = (
  all_permission_ids - 
  set(user.get_all_permissions())
)
```

should get you going.

> Am I wrong in my impression that a superuser has all permissions?

No, you're not. Superusers do have all permissions, and this is generally short-circuited, i.e. you'd only check whether the user is a superuser, and if so, no more permission checking should be done.

> Are there other ways to get all permissions for a user in the form of a Permission QuerySet?

Kind of. Something like

```
user_permissions_qs = Permission.objects.filter(id__in={p.id for p in user.get_all_permissions()})
```

could work, but is really not optimal performance-wise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! `missing_permissions = set(Permission.objects.all()) - set(user.get_all_permissions())` returns all permissions since the sets are not similar. The datatype of `Permission.objects.all()` is not the same as in `user.get_all_permissions()`, as the latter returns a list of strings with "content_type.codename" while Permissions' representation are "|"-separated. `p.id` is not a thing since it ``get_all_permissions() just returns a list of strings.

Comment: Ah, right, `get_all_permissions()` returns strings, let me fix that.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still confused on one bit: How come the `all_permission_ids`-dictionary has a length of 516 while `Permission.objects.values_list('content_type__app_label', 'codename')` has a length of 519?  `Permission.objects.values_list('content_type__app_label', 'codename').distinct()` also gives 519.

Comment: Well, would it be possible that there are duplicate permissions in your database?

Comment: Theoretically, absolutely: It is a database with 11 years of data and 8 years of development! I thought the distinct would handle it, but I suspect that only affects primary key. A quick peek at the [Django Github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py) also shows me that there is a unique-together on "content_type" + "codename" so I'm not really sure how the sets should be different when using a value_list of those two values.